# Update my textField every 5 seconds

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I'm just starting with Java and I need help please, I want to update my `JtextField` every 5 seconds, I searched something and I tried with `thread.sleep(5000)` but its not working (and i don't know why). Here is the code of my `JtextField`:

```
    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setText("0656");
    textField_1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 80));
    textField_1.setToolTipText("");
    textField_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textField_1.setBounds(212, 120, 600, 150);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: Where are you using `thread.sleep(5000)` ?

Comment: maybe you should post your entire code where you are try to **update** the textfield's value.

Comment: I used but it doesn't work, how can i do to show the textField_1.setText("0656") for 5 seconds and nothing after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is using class Timer.

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
              // textField_t.setText(YOUR TEXT); 
        }
    }, 0L, 5000L);
```

Comment: But that will show the value of the textField every 5 seconds, I only want to show the value for 5 seconds every time that the value were updated.

Comment: This is not what you asked in your original post. Do you mean that you want to show value into text field and then clear the text field? Kind of blinking?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake, Yes, I want to show the IF ("0656") for 5 second and then nothing until the value is updated

Comment: What does it mean "and then nothing?" Remove the value?

Comment: You can create 2 timers: one that shows value every 5 seconds, second that removes value every 5 seconds. The second timer's delay is 5 seconds also (instead of 0L).

Comment: I tryed with your code copyed two times and it doesn't work, it's only show the latest timer made

Comment: Have you changed the "delay" of the second timer?

Comment: This would update the text field outside the event dispatch thread. It's better to use a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of java.util.Timer.

Comment: It works, but for 1 milisecond I can see how change the "0656" for the "", but no problem, now, I'm trying to use the same timers for show the date and update every second:

Date fecha=new java.util.Date();
textField = new JTextField(fecha.toLocaleString());
textField.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 15));
textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
textField.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.textField.setBounds(362, 665, 300, 50);
frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
textField.setColumns(10);

Answer (score 1):

Use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) component for repetitive tasks with Swing GUI toolkit:

```
ActionListener task = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // Do stuff
            }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,task); // Execute task each 100 miliseconds
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remember that the 5000 is 5000 milliseconds and 1000 milliseconds is equal to 1 second.

```
 `javax.swing.Timer

  final Timer updater = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
  {
  // update JTextField
  }
  });
  JButton button = new JButton("Start");
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  updater.start();
  }
  });`
```